# What does this sentence mean? "Of service", "probable baby"... Are there some idioms lurking around?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does it mean? Wells's short story Catastrophe. What baby is meant?

> Minnie tried to take a cheerful view **of service—with a probable baby**.

Comment: Are you actually *reading* these stories yourself before asking here? Some context would be helpful. Is Minnie perhaps *pregnant* at that point in the narrative? Or [contemplating] taking a job "in service" with a family who might have a new baby on the way?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because while this sense of [domestic] **service** is obviously less common today than it was centuries ago, it's still easily found by consulting a dictionary. And the meaning of "a probable baby" should be obvious to anyone actually reading the containing narrative (but it must be context-dependent, so not relevant to a question *here*).

Comment: It's called '**A** Catastrophe'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Service* in this era and context meant "domestic service", that is, working as a maid or other domestic in a middle or upper class household.

*With a probable baby* I would guess means that she thought she was probably pregnant, but it is possible that it means something else in the story.

Comment: The story is about the proprietor of a small draper's shop, and his wife, facing the failure of the business, due to inability to pay wholesalers. They are no longer young. The wife thinks that she could go into domestic service, and there might be a baby to look after as part of that employment.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey that settles it, thank you 